# What is the name of this piece in the image attached?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

What is the shiny metal piece around the tube in the picture called?

Comment: It looks like a bimini tube eye-end fitting. Lots of types, sizes, makers. https://www.amazon.com/Amadget-Bimini-Hardware-Fitting-Stainless/dp/B073LTLY61/ref=asc_df_B073LTLY61/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312065655587&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17433485005732455424&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9010283&hvtargid=pla-568495808542&psc=1

Comment: @PhilSweet It’s best to post answers as answers.

Comment: @Eric's that is a shopping answer ... probably off topic, same as a shopping question

Comment: @jsotola Asking *what* something is called isn't a shopping question. The point of shopping questions not being allowed is that the become outdated after a couple of years. This answer will not become outdated; at least as far as what that fitting is called, not necessarily the brand.

Answer (score 0):

A chromed shock absorber or a chromed shock absorber cover.

Comment: I think it is just a housing for receiving and fastening the tubular steel in the furniture assembly.